# How to call an oracle function with out parameters with delphi?

Tags: java, oracle, delphi

I need to call an oracle function called `GetData` with the following parameters from Delphi:

```
(RESULT) NUMBER
P1 VARCHAR2 IN
P2 VARCHAR2 IN
P3 VARCHAR2 IN
P4 VARCHAR2 OUT
```

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
q := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
q.Connection := conn;
q.SQL.Add('BEGIN');
q.SQL.Add(' SELECT GetData(:IN_1,:IN_2,:IN_3,:OUT_1) into :OUT_2 from dual;');
q.SQL.Add('END;');

q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_1').DataType:=ftString;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_1').Direction:=pdInput;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_1').Size:=3;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_1').Value:='001';

q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_2').DataType:=ftString;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_2').Direction:=pdInput;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_2').Size:=15;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_2').Value:='88000000000';

q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_3').DataType:=ftString;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_3').Direction:=pdInput;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_3').Size:=64;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_3').Value:='';

q.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT_1').DataType:=ftString;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT_1').Direction:=pdOutput;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT_1').Size:=255;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT_1').Value:='';

q.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT_2').DataType:=ftInteger;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT_2').Direction:=pdOutput;
q.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT_2').Value:='0';

q.Open;

responseEdit.Text:=q.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT_1').Value;
```

However I get `ORA-06572: Function GETDATA has OUT arguments`. As far as I understand this, one cannot use a function with OUT parameters in a SELECT statement in Oracle...

So how to call it then?

---

In java, for example, I managed to do this with the following syntax:

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{ call ? := GetData(?,?,?,?)}");
```

Unfortunately it does not work in Delphi...

---

I also tried to call it with the syntax:

```
q.SQL.Add('BEGIN');
q.SQL.Add(' :OUT_2 := GetData(:IN_1,:IN_2,:IN_3,:OUT_1);');
q.SQL.Add('END;');
```

But Delphi seems to missunderstand the `:=` symbol as a parameter. So it comes to Oracle corrupted, and `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following := . ( @ % ; indicator` exception is thrown....Or if I remove spaces arounf `:=` already Delphi throws some general EOLEException.

---

I tried calling with `TADOStoredProc`:

```
stp := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
stp.Connection := conn;
//stp.ProcedureName:='GetData';    //also tried this
stp.ProcedureName:=':OUT_2 := GetData(:IN_1,:IN_2,:IN_3,:OUT_1)';
stp.Parameters.CreateParameter('OUT_2',ftInteger,pdOutput,4,0);
stp.Parameters.CreateParameter('IN_1',ftString,pdInput,3,'101');
stp.Parameters.CreateParameter('IN_2',ftString,pdInput,15,phoneEdit.Text);
stp.Parameters.CreateParameter('IN_3',ftString,pdInput,64,' ');
stp.Parameters.CreateParameter('OUT_1',ftString,pdOutput,255,' ');
stp.ExecProc;
```

it throws an unknown OleException. When I specify the proc name like `stp.ProcedureName:='GetData';`, it says `wrong number or types of parameters specified`.

---

I tried doing the same with `TADOCommand`:

```
cmd := TADOCommand.Create(nil);
cmd.Connection := conn;
cmd.CommandType := cmdStoredProc;
cmd.CommandText := ' :OUT_2 := GetData(:IN_1,:IN_2,:IN_3,:OUT_1); ';
...
```

Again Delphi throws an unknown OleException.

---

So either I use an incorrect syntax for both oracle and delphi, or I fail to pass parameters to delphi so, that it could format a correct call to oracle...

But all this does work, when calling an oracle function without OUT parameters, or when calling ms sql function (even with out parameters...). So what's wrong with it here?

Comment: Have you tried using TADOStoredProc? It is known to work with out parameters

Comment: Try calling q.ExecSQL instead and check your parameters.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas, please, see my edits...I've tried to, but to no success...Probably I am wrong with the syntax...or parameters initialization...I would be glad, if one could correct me...

Comment: @Jason calling `ExecSQL` does not change anything...All the same errors do happen...

Comment: @horgh Check on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, `TADOStoredProc` is known to Work with out parameters. 
Here is an SSCCE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ADMIN.GETDATA(IN_1 IN VARCHAR2, 
                                   IN_2 IN VARCHAR2, 
                                   IN_3 IN VARCHAR2, 
                                   OUT_1 IN OUT VARCHAR2) RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
    OUT_1 := IN_1 || IN_2 || IN_3;
    RETURN 5;
END;
```

On PL/SQL This is working:

```
BEGIN  
  DECLARE OUTVAR VARCHAR(255);
          RETVAR INTEGER;    
  BEGIN
     RETVAR:= ADMIN.GETDATA('A','B','C', OUTVAR);
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(OUTVAR);     
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RETVAR);         
  END;  
END;
```

The OutPut Page is:

```
ABC
5
```

Now the Delphi Code:

```
var Proc: TADOStoredProc;
    P: TParameter;
    Results: String;
begin
  Proc := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);
  try
    (* Set up the connection to an Oracle database *)
    Proc.Connection := MyADOConnection;

    (* Define the function Name *)
    Proc.ProcedureName := 'GETDATA';

    (* Let the FrameWork retrieve all the parameters from DataBase *)
    //Proc.Parameters.Refresh;
    //Set parameters values
    //Proc.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_1').Value := 'A';
    //Proc.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_2').Value := 'B';
    //Proc.Parameters.ParamByName('IN_3').Value := 'C';
    //Proc.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT1').Value := ''; //This will be overrided by the database.

    // **********************
    //          OR
    // **********************

    //Define it manually!
    begin
      //Defining the Return Value
      Proc.Parameters.CreateParameter('RETVAL', ftBCD (* or ftInteger *), pdReturnValue, 0, Unassigned);

      //Defining Input parameters 1, 2 and 3;

      Proc.Parameters.CreateParameter('IN1', ftString , pdInput, 4000 (* This is the Max *), 'A');

      //Collect the reference to update later
      P := Proc.Parameters.CreateParameter('IN2', ftString , pdInput, 4000 (* Length for a    *), Unassigned);

      Proc.Parameters.CreateParameter('IN3', ftString , pdInput, 4000 (* ftString param  *), 'C');

      Proc.Parameters.CreateParameter('OUT1', ftString , pdOutput, 4000, Unassigned);

      P.Value := 'B';

      Proc.ExecProc;

      // Expected : [Return Value : 5]~[Out Var: ABC]
      Results := Format('[Return Value : %s]~[Out Var: %s]',
                        [VarToStr(Proc.Parameters.ParamByName('RETVAL').Value),
                         VarToStr(Proc.Parameters.ParamByName('OUT1').Value)]);
      Proc.Close;

      // ACTUAL : [Return Value : 5]~[Out Var: ABC]
      ShowMessage(Results);


      //IT WORKS!!
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Proc);
  end;
```

Comment: My mistake was specifying the return value type as `pdOutput` and trying to write some query instead of the proc name into the `ProcedureName`

Comment: Can we have example in Java?